# Reverse Pattern of Digits from 10. (pattern problems)

Tags: python

This is the pattern that I want to print.

1
3 2
6 5 4
10 9 8 7

Now I have a solution but I don't know **how** exactly it is working.

solution:

```
length = 6
start = 1
stop = 2
currentNumber = stop
for row in range(stop, length):
    for col in range(start, stop):
        currentNumber -= 1
        print(currentNumber, end=" ")
    print(" ")
    start = stop
    stop += row
    currentNumber = stop
```

This is How I think it is working:

```
# for row in range(2, 6): 2, 3, 4, 5,
# for col in range(1, 2):
#  currentnum = 2-1 = 1
#  print( 1 )
#  start = stop (start = 2)
#  stop += 2 (row = 2,3,4,5) so now stop = 2 + 2 = 4
# currentNumber = 4

# for row in range(4, 6): 4,5
# for col in range(2, 4): 2, 3 means 2 time will loop run
#  currentnum = 4-1 = 3,
#  currentnum = 3-2 = 2
#  print( 3, 2 )
#  start = stop (start = 4)
#  stop += 3 (stro = 4+3 = 7)
#  currentnum = 7

                    **PROBLEM** 

# for row in range(7, 6):    
# for col in range(4, 7): 5,6,7 means 3 time will loop run
#  currentnum = 7-1 = 6,
#  currentnum = 7-2 = 5,
#  currentnum = 7-3 = 4,
#  print( 6, 5, 4)
#  start = stop (start = 7)
#  stop += 3 (stro = 7+3 = 11)
#  currentnum = 11
```

Here is the problem (`talking from the #commented calculations`):

```
for i in range(11, 6):
    for j in range(4, 7):
        print("h")
    print("k")
print("j")
```

This For loop will not execute because of (11, 6).

That's where My calculations went wrong and know I have NO clue again how this solution is working.
Anyone have better solution or explanation for the current solution will be appreciated.

**just want to know how the code is working**

Thankyou.

Comment: 1st on the problem when you ```printing``` remove the ```" "``` from the ```k``` and ```j``` that you have inside the ```print```

Comment: Then change this ```for i in range(11, 6)``` to this ```for i in range(11, 6, -1)``` in order to work.

Comment: @iamcoder If you want to know what you are doing is right or wrong then set breakpoints and debug. Any IDE supports debugging, only when we debug we understand the problem. Good luck.

Comment: @bilakos I can put limit in reverse but it is not in solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your understanding was re-writing the first for loop every time stop was changed. This shouldn't be done, however, as the for loop only calculates at the start so changing the variable `stop` shouldn't have an effect on a loop once it's already running, if that makes sense. I corrected your 'understanding' section here:

```
#### for loop does not change
# for row in range(2, 6): 2, 3, 4, 5,

### for loop 2 ###
#     for col in range(1, 2):
#         currentNumber -= 1  # 2-1 = 1
#         print(1)
#      start = stop  # (start = 2)
#      stop += 2  # (row currently = 2) so now stop = 2 + 2 = 4
#      currentNumber = 4

### for loop 3 ###
#     for col in range(2, 4): 2, 3 means 2 time will loop run
#         currentnum = 4-1 = 3,
#         currentnum = 3-2 = 2
#         print(3, 2)
#     start = stop  # (start = 4)
#     stop += 3  # (row currently = 3) so now stop = 4 + 3 = 7
#     currentnum = 7

### for loop 4 ###
#     for col in range(4, 7):  # 4, 5, 6 i.e. loop 3 times
#         currentnum = 7-1 = 6,
#         currentnum = 6-1 = 5
#         currentnum = 5 - 1 = 4
#         print(6, 5, 4)
#     start = stop  # (start = 7)
#     stop += 4  # (row currently = 4) so now stop = 7 + 4 = 11
#     currentnum = 11

### for loop 5 ###
#     for col in range(7, 11):  # 7, 8, 9, 10 i.e. loop 4 times
#         currentnum = 11 - 1 = 10
#         currentnum = 10 - 1 = 9
#         currentnum = 9 - 1 = 8
#         currentnum = 8 - 1 = 7
#         print(10, 9, 8, 7)
#     start = stop  # (start = 11)
#     stop += 5  # (row currently = 5) so now stop = 11 + 5 = 16
#     currentnum = 16
```

Hope this makes sense but feel free to ask for clarification. Note that the last few lines don't matter since it is the last for loop.

Comment: Thankyou for your time I really appreciate it. So key here is First for loop does not change.

Comment: Yes it sees the `stop` variable and saves the number, it can't change during the for loop. This is why, say if you are using a for loop to go through a list, it is problematic to remove items from the list within said for loop (since it expects a certain number of items but you are removing them)